# Are quantities of units considered singular or plural?

Tags: grammar, numbers

Whenever I recite recipes or measurements in my head, the quantity of units is usually plural, but I find myself using singular verbs. For instance, "three cups of butter *yields* 12 batches" or "when measuring speed, five people *gives* a 20% increase." I figured that since three cups is obviously plural, it should be "three cups of butter yield 12 batches" and "when measuring speed, five people give a 20% increase." But that just doesn't sound right at all, to my ears at least.
This might also just be a poor understanding of English on my part, since I didn't grow up with fluent English speaker, but I'm certain that I've heard other people (including my grammar puritan English teacher) talk like this before.

Answer (score 0):

These phrases are treated as collective nouns, which get singular verbs. If you use a plural verb, it gives the impression that each item in the collective is acting individually. For instance

> Five people give a 20% tip.

means that each person gave a 20% tip, not that the group of people gave a single 20% tip.

Comment: Absolutely, but if you are talking about _countable_ ingredients then the verb _should_ be plural. For instance "Four eggs make two omelettes" or even "A dozen eggs make six omelettes". In the latter case 'A dozen' is a number, not a collective noun.

Comment: @BoldBen Notional agreement is still available in most cases. "A dozen chillies is not too much.' The universal grinder principle.